# Create a unique group number for a color if they have any attributes that match

Tags: excel, dataframe

I have a list of names that have references. I want to create a unique group identifier based on if they have any name or reference in common or relation. I have potentially thousands of names and references.

I'm don't know how to describe my problem well enough to try to search for an answer.

What my input might look like:

| name | reference 1 | reference 2 | reference 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| green | 1 | 4 | 5 |
| blue | 4 | 6 | 7 |
| orange | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| yellow | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| violet | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| magenta | 11 | 12 | red |
| brown | 10 | 14 | 15 |
| teal | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| gray | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

I am hoping to assign a unique group to a name like below.

| name | reference 1 | reference 2 | reference 3 | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| green | 1 | 4 | 5 | 1 |
| blue | 4 | 6 | 7 | 1 |
| orange | 8 | 9 | 10 | 2 |
| yellow | 11 | 12 | 13 | 1 |
| violet | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| magenta | 11 | 12 | red | 1 |
| brown | 10 | 14 | 15 | 2 |
| teal | 16 | 17 | 18 | 3 |
| gray | 19 | 20 | 21 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 |

I tried CHATgpt and didn't get anywhere with python, I also tried to index match in excel and haven't been able to get anywhere remotely close.

To explain how the group is chosen: Red has a reference of 1, 2, and 3. Green also has a reference of 1 so it will be part of the same group. The group is chosen arbitrarily but I started at 1 and moved higher in number. Blue has a reference of 4 which is shared with green so it will be apart of the same group as red and green.

[Hand drawn picture of what my problem looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLb0J.jpg)

Comment: Are you saying this table might have thousands of *rows*, or thousands of *columns*, or both?

Comment: @ScottHunter both

Comment: Please explain the logic for the group value - otherwise it is hard to help you ...

Comment: @ike Red has a reference of 1, 2, and 3. Green also has a reference of 1 so it will be part of the same group. The group is chosen arbitrarily but I started at 1 and moved higher in number. Blue has a reference of 4 which is shared with green so it will be apart of the same group as red and green.

Comment: what happens in the instance where a name shares a reference with multiple groups

Comment: @LafaMan The groups are created based on the name and their references. If a name shares a reference with another name then it needs to be a part of the same group.

Comment: @RyanK Thats my question. Using your example, let's say black's references are 1 , 8 and 17. Which group does it go into.

Comment: @LafaMan If you added black which has those references then black would bridge group 1, 2 and 3: since 1 is in group 1, 8 is in group 2, and 17 is in group 3. Then the names in the groups need to change so that they could be in the same group, for example every name in group 2 and 3 would change to group 1.

Comment: When you tried this in Python, what form was the data in?

Comment: @ScottHunter The data I'm working with will be in excel format and I'll transpose it to fit whatever form will work. My efforts failed miserably earlier, but I had it like this. data = [
    ['red', 1, 2, 3],
    ['green', 1, 4, 5],
    ['blue', 4, 6, 7],
    ['orange', 8, 9, 10],
    ['yellow', 11, 12, 13],
    ['violet', 1, 2, 3],
    ['magenta', 11, 12, 'red'],
    ['brown', 10, 14, 15],
    ['teal', 16, 17, 18],
    ['gray', 19, 20, 21],
    [1, 2, 3, 4],

Comment: This sounds like a version of Union-Find.

Comment: @ScottHunter thank you, I think that's pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

This works w/ the data as in your comment:

```
groups = {0:set()} # 0 is a dummy group
for d in data:
    ds = set(d)
    old_gs = []
    # Identify overlapping groups
    for g,x in groups.items():
        if len(ds.intersection(x)) > 0:
            old_gs.append(g) 
    if old_gs == []:
        # New group!
        new_gnum = max(groups.keys())+1
        groups[new_gnum] = ds 
    else:
        # Combine later matching groups with first one
        gx = old_gs[0]
        for g in old_gs[1:]:
            groups[gx] = groups[gx].union(groups[g])
            del groups[g]
        # Add in this row
        groups[gx] = groups[gx].union(ds)
# Append group number to each row
for d in data:
    ds = set(d)
    for g,x in groups.items():
        if len(ds.intersection(x)) > 0:
            d.append(g)
            break
```